# how to grab info about all the Sharing done through SharePoint in Office 365 Using Graph Rest endpoint

Tags: sharepoint, graph, office365

I'm trying to prepare the consolidated report on all the sharing done through graph rest endpoint. It would be helpful if anyone suggest the endpoint available to do such activity; or any other approach. But prefer Graph Rest endpoint.. Appreciate your help in advance.